# Is it safe to have 48V supplied on a AudioBox USB96 combo XLR - 1/4" jack and plug in a guitar

Tags: xlr, phantom

I have a AudioBox USB96 interface.  The box has two XLR 1/4" Combo jacks.  I have a mic that requires 48V and is plugged into one of the connectors.  I would like to plug my guitar into the second jack, but it is not clear to me if that is safe to do or not.  The owners manual only mentions the XLR being dangerous to ribbon mics when phantom power is on, so by omission, it seems to indicate that a guitar would be safe.  Has anyone done this and had success? Or is it going to damage the AudioBox interface when I plug that guitar in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the guitar using the 1/4 inch input. 48V is only applied to the XLR.